# L2FWD dpdk application result

Tags: dpdk

I have generated traffic via pktgen dpdk on one VM and L2fwd on another VM. Two ports which are virtio-net are attached via internal network. I wanted to confirm If I am getting right results for L2 forwarding being done when traffic is generated.[L2fwd result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1zur.png) [L2fwd result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka0ZA.png) [L2fwd result 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XzEI.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [L2 forwarding using pktgen as traffic generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64476596/l2-forwarding-using-pktgen-as-traffic-generator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since virtual box is used on host linux machine, the configuration need to be correct in network settings to allows packet flow from host to guest. By changing `host only` mode in the adapter settings one can send packet to and fro from the desired NIC.

Comment: @SaifUllah please accept and upvote if the live debug solved the issue for you.

Comment: Yes Sure. The live debug  did solve the problem. Thank you so much for your time.